# migration to JBoss 5.1 - Failed to create a new SAX parser

Tags: jboss, migration, classloader, isolation

I am trying to deploy my application (packed in .war file) that work properly on JBoss 4.2.3 to JBoss 5.1 (using java 5).

Currently during deployment time I see in the server.log the error:

> ... Caused by:
>   org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException:
>   Failed to create a new SAX parser
>
> ...
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration

According to this [thread](http://community.jboss.org/thread/2357?tstart=0) in JBoss forums, I need to isolate my application.
My questions:

1. according to [JBoss 5.1 Release Notes](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Release_Notes/510GA/readme.html) - *The major differences with the existing configurations is that call-by-value and deployment isolation are enabled by default.* Therefore do I really need implicitly set my application isolated?
2. I thought that isolation is mainly needed when the same application server runs several applications that collides with each other. In my case I am trying to run only one application. So again is the isolation required?
3. If the answer is positive to the above question and I need to enforce isolation - how can I configure it? suppose my war file is called 'foo'. do I have to insert to the jboss-web.xml the section:

```xml
<jboss-web> 
  <loader-repository>
 tld.mydomain:loader=foo.war
 </loader-repository>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 6):

OK Apperently the solution is to remove xerces.jar from my web-inf/lib

Isolation won't work due to some bug. See [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhydoigetjavalangClassCastExceptionorgapachexercesparsersXIncludeAwareParserConfigurationinAS-5)

Answer (score 1):

Failed to create a new sax parser error is due to the availability of unwanted JAR files in WAR and EAR if there. So by deleting those unwanted JARS this error is been cleared.

Comment: How to identify which are jars are unwanted>

Comment: xercesImpl.jar alone should do it.  It conflicts with the internal version jBoss loads.